# Why expense details are asked for UK business visa? How can I say the trip expenses are to be taken care by my employer in the application form?

Tags: uk, business-travel

I am applying for 6 months business visitor visa. For this trip all my expenses are to be borne by my company.

Then why I have to fill in the below fields.

- Do you have savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares?
- How much do you spend each month on living costs?
- How much of your total monthly income is given to your family members and other dependants?

And how to fill in the below fields?

- The total amount of money you have for this trip?
- Is someone other than you paying for all or a part of your trip?
  can I choose yes and select 'others' in the relationship field and mention Employer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UK has categorized the Business Visitor Visa as Standard Visitor Visa where you have to prove your purpose of visits and intentions. Also no matter who is sponsoring you the key factor for visa approval is for your reason to return to your home country.

> Then why I have to fill in the below fields.
>
> Do you have savings, properties or other income, for example from
>   stocks and shares? How much do you spend each month on living costs?
>   How much of your total monthly income is given to your family members
>   and other dependants?

You need to demonstrate your financial standings within your country, even if your employer is sponsoring your Business Visit. Please make sure you give 100% transparency in your visa application

> And how to fill in the below fields?
>
> The total amount of money you have for this trip? Is someone other
>   than you paying for all or a part of your trip? can I choose yes and
>   select 'others' in the relationship field and mention Employer?

You need to provide an estimated cost of your tour which actually demonstrates how well you have planned your visit, this includes your all costs while staying in the United Kingdom.
You can select other and mention the sponsorship from your employer and you need to provide reasonable supporting documents like NOC from Employer, Letter of Consent from the Employer and supportive documents from your employer.

It is your responsibility to satisfy Entry Clearance Officer and they do not assume anything and only make their decision based on the provided document.

Best of Luck for your upcoming visit!